# How to transform a list (of sums) into list of summands?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Suppose you have the list `list={a,Sin[b+c],d+c}`. What I want is to transform all elements of `list` with head `Plus` into a list again, so that the desired output would be `{a,Sin[b+c],d,c}`. Simply using `List@@` or `/.Plus->List` will for sure not work since it either transforms all heads (including those that should be left unchanged) or e.g. replaces function arguments.

So what is a neat way to accomplish this potentially very easy task?

Comment: Does the order matter, i.e., `{a, Sin[b+c],c,d}` vs your result.

Comment: @ciao The order does not matter. All elements will be symbolic terms that will be summed up at the very end of a long computation. But thanks for pointing this out - I didn't think about the importance while posting the question :)

Comment: Then *Jens*' answer is the way to go...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
list = {a, Sin[b + c], d + c};

Replace[list, HoldPattern[Plus[x__]] :> Sequence[x], 1]

(* ==> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}} *)
```

Here, `HoldPattern` is needed to prevent the `Plus` from being swallowed. I use `Replace` because it allows me to specify the level `1` at which the replacement is to occur.

Comment: Not what they're after... c d s/b sequence...

Comment: @Ciao Oh, right...

Comment: And if order matters.... whole 'nother ball-o-wax, +1 though ;-)

Comment: @ciao Thanks - you're right that the order could be tricky because you have to deal with the lexical rules.

Comment: Yep - though I'm not even sure what OP has in mind - if the list is a list of things not strings, than MMA will reorder the `Plus` arguments already, I'm thinking perhaps typo... or order doesn't matter.

Comment: @ciao In any case it shows that you were reading very carefully. I didn't even notice that point at first.

Comment: @Jens This is exactly what I am after since ordering is unimportant for me. Thanks for your repl and brief explanation. I will just wait a couple of days with accepting to see if other solutions appear :)

Comment: You can also do `Replace[list, Plus -> Sequence, {2}, Heads -> True]`

Comment: @mfvonh Yes, this option for `Heads` is another nice thing about `Replace`.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {a, Sin[b + c], d + c, g + h + i};
```

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[Plus[a__] :> List @@ a, Position[list, _Plus, 1]] @ list
```

{a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}, {g, h, i}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list /. {a_[_Plus] :> a, Plus -> List}
```

> ```
> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}}
> ```

```
Replace[list, Plus -> List, 2, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}}
> ```

```
ReplacePart[list, Position[list, Plus, 2] -> List]
```

> ```
> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}}
> ```

```
MapAt[List &, list, Position[list, Plus, 2]]
```

> ```
> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}}
> ```

```
list[[## & @@ First[Position[list, Plus, 2]]]] = List; list
```

> ```
> {a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `Cases`:

```
list = {a, Sin[b + c], d + c, g + h + i};

Cases[list, x_ :> If[SameQ[Head[x], Plus], List @@ x, x]]

(*{a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}, {g, h, i}}*)
```

Or using `If` and `Map`:

```
If[Head[#] === Plus, # /. Plus -> Function[{##}], #] & /@ list

(*{a, Sin[b + c], {c, d}, {g, h, i}}*)
```